# Append an element to a new one in the same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

> **THE PROBLEM IS NOT THE LABEL *FOR* ATTRIBUTE, IT WORKS, MY PROBLEM IS THAT I NEED TO RENDER THE DOCUMENT AS EXPECTED**

Getting crazy on this code! Why it doesn't works?

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tonino" />
</div>

<script>
   var $el=$('input[name="tonino"]');
   var el=$el.prop('name');
   $el.before('<label for="'+el+'" />');
   $el.appendTo($el.parent().find('label:first'));
</script>
```

I'm expecting:

```
<div>
  <label for="tonino">
     <input type="checkbox" name="tonino" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? It seems to work fine to me...but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do much better to get help. What are you expecting? What are you getting instead?

Comment: @Tricky12 take a look now please ;)

Comment: `$(this)` ?????

Comment: Why don't you just use `$.wrap()` http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ ?

Comment: @Ejaz that's the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Answer was posted since it contained a better solution than the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach using `$.wrap()` http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
var cb = $('input[name="tonino"]');
cb.wrap($('<label />', {
    'for': cb.attr('name')
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want like below (check HTML through browser console to see code working properly or not?):-

```js
var el=$('input[name="tonino"]');
el.before('<label for="'+el.attr('name')+'" />'+el.attr('name')+'<label>');
el.appendTo(el.parent().find('label:first'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="tonino" />
</div>
```

Note:- jquery library needed too.